# "SC.EXE config" and dollar sign in service name

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-service, windows

Say I want to make Windows Service startup dependent on SQL Server.

In my case service name for SQL Server is **MSSQL$SQL11** (SQL11 is SQL Server instance name)

However, when I issue this command:

**SC.EXE config MyService depend= MSSQL$SQL11**

everything after the dollar sign is ignored. When I go to "Dependencies" tab in "Services" SQL Server is not listed. When I check matching registry key it becomes clear why: it only has **MSSQL**. At this point I have to edit registry by hand to change **MSSQL** to **MSSQL$SQL11** and then everything works as expected.

Putting quotes around **MSSQL$SQL11** doesn't help.

Is there a way to specify **$** in the middle of the SC.EXE argument string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - one needs to put double quotes around dollar sign:

**SC.EXE config MyService depend= MSSQL"$"SQL11**

Comment: Did you try `SC.EXE config MyService depend= "MSSQL$SQL11"` ? I'm not sure if it works, just wondering if you tried it.

Comment: @gparent, perhaps you missed "Putting quotes around MSSQL$SQL11 doesn't help" in the question.